# How to solve spacebrew error: the server responded with a status of 426 (Upgrade Required)?

Tags: node.js, websocket

1. I cloned the [Spacebrew repo](https://github.com/Spacebrew/spacebrew)
2. I installed the `websocket` and the `forever` modules (`npm install ws` and `npm install forever-monitor`)
3. I started Spacebrew (`node node_server_forever.js`)
4. I went to `http://localhost:9000/` or `http://localhost:9000/admin/index.html` on my browser and the page displays:

> Upgrade Required

There are two errors on the console:

```
http://localhost:9000/favicon.ico
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 
 (Upgrade Required)
http://localhost:9000/
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426
 (Upgrade Required)
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin interface is not hosted by the SB Server. It is a static page. There is a copy accessible at http://spacebrew.github.io/spacebrew/admin/admin.html which will attempt to connect to a localhost SB server on port 9000. you can provide querystrings to connect to a remote server or different port: http://spacebrew.github.io/spacebrew/admin/admin.html?server=specialdoma.in&port=9999

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand this + I run into [this issue](https://github.com/Spacebrew/spacebrew/issues/55) because I was using an old version of node.js.